# Get lines by a unique portion of the line, and display only the first occurrence of that unique portion

Tags: bash, sorting, cut

I'm trying to write a script that looks at a part of a line, does a `sort -u` or something to look for unique occurrences, and then displays the output, sorted by the ORIGINAL ordering of the lines. In other words, only the FIRST occurrence of that part of the line would show up.

I managed to do it using `cut`, but my output just displays the cut portion of the data. How could I do it so that it gets the entire line?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
cut -d, -f6 infile.txt | cut -c4-11 | grep -n . | sort -t: -k2,2 -u | sort -t: -k1n,1 | cut -d: -f2-
```

I know the data doesn't have an extra `:` or a `,` in a place that would break this script. But this only outputs the data that was unique. How can I get the entire line? I would prefer to stay away from perl, but awk is okay (though I don't know it very well).

#### Sample:

If the input file is this (note, the ABCDEFGH is not real, I just put it there to illustrate what I mean):

```
A....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130718......,.........,...........,......
B....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130714......,.........,...........,......
C....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130718......,.........,...........,......
D....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130719......,.........,...........,......
E....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130713......,.........,...........,......
F....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130714......,.........,...........,......
G....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130630......,.........,...........,......
H....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130718......,.........,...........,......
```

My program outputs:

```
20130718
20130714
20130719
20130713
20130630
```

I want to see:

```
A....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130718......,.........,...........,......
B....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130714......,.........,...........,......
D....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130719......,.........,...........,......
E....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130713......,.........,...........,......
G....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130630......,.........,...........,......
```

Comment: You need to provide sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `awk` is your best bet. Here's a mysterious example:

```
awk -F, '!seen[substr($6,4,8)]++' infile.txt
```

Explanation:

```
options:
  -F,              set the field separator to ,

condition:
  substr($6,4,8)   up to 8 characters starting at the fourth character
                   of the sixth field
  seen[...]++      seen is an associative array (dictionary). Increment the
                   value associated with ..., and return the old value
  !seen[...]++     if there was no old value, perform the action


action:
  There is no action, only a condition, so the default action is
  performed if the test succeeds. The default action is to print
  the line. So the  line will be printed if the relevant characters of
  the sixth field haven't yet been seen.
```

Test:

```
$ awk -F, '!seen[substr($6,4,8)]++' <<EOF
> A....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130718......,.........,...........,......
> B....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130714......,.........,...........,......
> C....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130718......,.........,...........,......
> D....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130719......,.........,...........,......
> E....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130713......,.........,...........,......
> F....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130714......,.........,...........,......
> G....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130630......,.........,...........,......
> H....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130718......,.........,...........,......
> EOF
A....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130718......,.........,...........,......
B....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130714......,.........,...........,......
D....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130719......,.........,...........,......
E....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130713......,.........,...........,......
G....,....,...........,.....,....,...20130630......,.........,...........,......
$
```

Comment: This seems correct, I've upvoted. I'll checkmark it when I confirm it works

Comment: @durron597: It definitely works with your sample input. I hope it's a motivation to learn more awk; definitely worth the trouble.

Comment: I tested it with `head -n1000`, it worked, I wanted to test it with `head -n1000000` before checkmarking (the file is very large). Also, I definitely agree, I just recently got good enough with `sed s/` that I use it often now, it's time to learn `awk` :)

Comment: Cool and succint solution! I upvoted this answer and deleted mine.